remove restrictions for local file and resource access
My Tauri v2 app is intended as a GUI for different, purely local softwares. Since no web access is necessary, but access to different, unforeseeable file and resource locations - how can I remove the restrictions for loading resources (img, css, js)? So far I helped myself by just using Rust functions for loading file contents and then injecting it into the DOM elements, but that's not a convenient way for loading images. So far it seems to me I cannot do that in Tauri v2, enabling unrestricted local access?

With capabilities (among others):
"core:path:default",
"core:resources:default",
"dialog:default"

and in main.rs:
.plugin(tauri_plugin_dialog::init())
.plugin(tauri_plugin_fs::init())
.plugin(tauri_plugin_shell::init())

I am able to use:
import { path } from "@tauri-apps/api"
import { save, open } from "@tauri-apps/api/dialog"

I am still searching all these as well, so not really sure what is actually needed, but I hope this at least helps you looking further.
